# Checking if the Internet and a particular site are up in JavaScript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page which runs locally on my device, and I would like to use AJAX or normal JavaScript to check if the device is connected to the Internet **and** if a particular site is up.

Additionally, I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of entries in an RSS feed through AJAX, but I've never programmed around RSS before. This isn't as big of a priority, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Ajax, the loading of scripts and images is not subject to the same-origin policy, so you can query for their existence (but not read their contents) cross-domain.  If you know a particular image on the site, you can use the `onload` event handler of a `new Image` to test if a site is up:

```
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function() { alert("site is up!") }
i.onerror = function() { alert("site is not up!") }
i.src = "/favicon.ico";
```

`/favicon.ico` is on a huge number of major sites, since it's required for favicon functionality in older IE. Not every site of the Web has it (indeed, not every site on the Web has a favicon), but it will work for major sites like Google, Wikipedia, Stack Overflow, etc.

`/favicon.ico` is nice for cross-site support, but if you only want to target one specific site, simply find an image on that site and query for its existence.

Comment: Oh, this is genius! Hadn't thought about doing that. Now, when will `i.onerror` be called (i.e. when does it return an error)?

Comment: `onerror` will fire when either 1) the request returns an error code (i.e. not a 2XX or 3XX HTTP response -- when the site is down, the image is not present, or some server-side error occurred) or 2) the resource fetched is not recognized as an image.  Case #2 might occur if the browser doesn't understand `.ico`, but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), `.ico` is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Is there any way to do something similar, but with a smaller target? The favicon I would have to use there is 3.44kB and that's 30MB/day if I'm checking every 10 sec.

Comment: If you only want to test a particular site, maybe you can find a smaller image on that site? I only suggested the favicon because it's consistent across a lot of different sites. Any image will do, so check out the site and see if there are any smaller images you can use.

Comment: Also, it's quite possible that you won't actually use that much data. Thanks to HTTP caching, all requests for the image after the first will probably return a [`304 Not Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) HTTP code, instead of the actual image data. This requires 1) your client browser caching the image and 2) the server being configured to send 304 responses when appropriate.  Both of these are quite likely -- only #1 might be questionable if it's on a mobile device. I'd suggest testing it in Wireshark to see what is actually sent over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Cross site Ajax is forbidden due to security concerns. A few work arounds would be to either use greasemonkey/userscripts(if this is just for personal use), or a plugin such as flash or java

Comment: Or JSONP. You do not have to use so limiting solutions as Flash or Java, where you need proper support on the client side.

Comment: JSONP wouldn't be valid here because you can't check the state of the script being downloaded

Comment: Of course it would be valid, if you are able to take different approach. Simple solution is to log the time when JSONP request started and when the callback was called. If you do it properly, you will get information about every request, including time of response or the information, that it has not been completed. That is enough to check the connection. The only thing you need is support on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There is basic support for

```
navigator.online
//Events
window.onOnline
window.onOffline
```

on desktop browsers and support on Android. This might not completely answer your question, but I thought its worth sharing anyway :)