# telneting ip/port in java/jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to make a script that telnet ip port to see if the server is up or down. (like how you do in window command prompt. cmd [enter] => telnet 11.111.11.11 200   (ip& port)and if the the connection is successful, program will return true else false. I need this code to be really efficient since this function will go into the forloop where I do all the displays on the website for each ip. Thnx in advance

P.S
Ops I meant java/jsp my bad haha

Comment: With JavaScript? I doubt that this is possible (without exploiting security holes in browsers).

Comment: Due to the astonishingly massive abuse potential of this feature, I'm sure you can't do it.

Comment: You definitely can't do this in JavaScript. However, if all you really want to do is check if a site is up or down, see this question/answer that tests for the existence of favicons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834503/checking-if-the-internet-and-a-particular-site-are-up-in-javascript-ajax

Comment: So, quick sanity check: you want to check if a bunch of telnet servers are up or down?

Comment: I'm trying to check if certain ip address with certain port is listening or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("java.sun.com");
        int port = 80;
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);

        // Create an unbound socket
        Socket sock = new Socket();

        // This method will block no more than timeoutMs.
        // If the timeout occurs, SocketTimeoutException is thrown.
        int timeoutMs = 2000;   // 2 seconds
        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```