# How do I check a remote domain for SSL, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl

Is it possible in JavaScript to check a remote domain for SSL? The use case is, a user visits my site and enters their domain name into a form, and my JavaScript queries their domain to see if it uses SSL then displays an "SSL" if it does.

I am using jQuery (1.8.2) so I try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://the-domain-entered',
  crossDomain: true,
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log('success: ' + data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
  console.log('fail: ' + data.statusText);
});
```

This always returns:

```
fail: error
```

Comment: Well, whether or not the other domain supports SSL, what it might *not* do is allow cross-origin XHR.

Comment: By default, a script on site A cannot read the contents of a resource on site B if sites A and B are on different origins. See: [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This restriction can be relaxed is site B serves [CORS headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) that allow access by site A.

Comment: Related: [Checking if the Internet and a particular site are up in JavaScript/AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11834503/710446)

Comment: You could try using http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: doesn't the "s" in https give this away?